# Render a template in layout with liquid and rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, liquid

I'm building an app where I let users to edit their template and layout. I store the templates in the database. I have a model which is called Theme and Template, where Theme has_many templates. The liquid code and HTML of each template is stored in the content attribute, `template.content`.
The main Template is called "theme" and the other "page". So I want to enable the method include so I can put `{{ include page }}` in the layout template.

I have this so far

```
<% if current_site.theme %>
<% @site = current_site %>
<% @theme = current_site.theme %>
<% @template = @theme.templates.find_by_name("theme") %>
<% Liquid::Template.file_system = Liquid::LocalFileSystem.new(@template) %>
<% liquid = Liquid::Template.parse(@template.content) %>
<%= raw liquid.render('site' => @site)  %>
<% end %>
```

But I get this error

```
Liquid error: can't convert Template into String
```

How can I render this?

Answer (score -1):

```
content = @template.content

liquid = Liquid::Template.parse(layout).render(content)
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.